# Why do boost::iterator_facade::operator[] and boost::iterator_range::operator[] have inconsistent return types

Tags: c++, boost

See example in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b164340b70de1770

`boost::iterator_facade::operator[]` is defined as:

```
typename boost::detail::operator_brackets_result<Derived,Value,reference>::type
    operator[](difference_type n) const
{
    typedef boost::detail::use_operator_brackets_proxy<Value,Reference> use_proxy;

    return boost::detail::make_operator_brackets_result<Derived>(
        this->derived() + n
        , use_proxy()
    );
}
```

But `boost::iterator_range::operator[]` is defined as:

```
reference operator[]( difference_type at ) const
{
    BOOST_ASSERT( at >= 0 && at < size() );
    return m_Begin[at];
}
```

Now there is a problem because `iterator_range::operator[]` may return a reference to a temporary object created by `iterator_facade::operator[]`. For example, `boost::reversed_range<const std::vector<int>>::operator[]` has such behavior.

I read the explanation in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#operator, but can still not understand.

Comment: Yup. Time to file a bug report.

Comment: Can you show us an _actual_ code example where "the wrong thing" is happening? When I try to literally mimick the example you hint at in prose, I get this (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90f0987eb36e4bab) which looks fine and doesn't trip any sanitizers I use

Comment: @sehe Please see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b164340b70de1770

Comment: Perhaps just add it to the question. It's a convincing example. +1